# Winterbash 2020! Join us on Travel!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It'd be really cool to see Travel members compete on the Winterbash this year!

It [starts in a few days](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/) and if you can especially target hats that improve the website, that'd be fantastic. We also usually have an informal challenge in the [Travel Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to see who on travel is leading with the most awesome hats.

If you're going to enter/compete, or just excited about hats, add your name as an answer below, and prepare yourself for the hats challenge!

(this is just to get people excited, everyone is entered by default)

Comment: um, what _is_ "Winterbash"?

Comment: It's a fun activity hosted by SE where you can earn hats to put on your avatar by doing different activities around sites e.g. asking, flagging etc. There is usually a competition to see who can get as many hats as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I always enjoy Winterbash, especially finding as many unique hats as possible. I'm counting down the days! :)

Answer (score 4):

Count me in! Hoping to beat Mark this year :-)

Comment: bring it on!! :D

Answer (score 3):

I will have more time than usual. Not done badly last few years.

Count me in.

Added near the end of the bash:
Some competition would have been nice. Next year?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to participate last year, but didn't get the opportunity to do so. I'm definitely doing it this year :)

Answer (score 3):

Despite my low rep (and hence no access to some moderation activities and hats), I enjoy answering here and I will be active in the next weeks. A couple of years ago I partecipated to SO Winterbash and I got quite many hats! Keep us excited ;)

Comment: You may earn a lot of rep while participating and get access to more moderation lists. And there are a lot of hats everybody can get.

Comment: @Willeke I like the rep thing: if I have a lot of rep, it means I'm very helpful and cool ;) But here it is about traveling (= enjoying life to the top) so it's just nice to share. At the moment I'm preparing a "great" answer about Vietnam, hopefully it will include many relevant and interesting infos. Let's go with the bash!!

Comment: Great answer (in my view) on that Vietnam Q. Hope more people will see it.

Comment: @Willeke I'm glad of a super feedback from a top user and moderator!! :)))

Comment: Looks like you now have twice the rep you had when you posted your answer here. Well done.

Comment: @Willeke ...plus four hats ;) No, seriously, good fun!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give it a try this year, I'm going to prepare some questions about upcoming travels !